# Temporary Disable Edit Action in ASP.NET MVC without Delete Its Action and View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a request from customer to disable edit function on a survey module, but this still unclear. For temporary, it should be removed from view so, user cannot edit the survey.

So, I removed the edit button on the Index view, but I can still access the edit page through the address bar, for example: `http://localhost:1306/Survey/Edit/1`.

I cannot delete the Edit Action and Edit View, because the requirement is still unclear. Is there any way to handle this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NonAction` attribute or make the method `private`, both solutions will work:

```
[NonAction]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
}

private ActionResult Edit()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works with private, but I cannot find `[NoAction]` attribute?
`The type or namespace name 'NoAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Willy my bad, it's called `NonAction`

Comment: Should I placed `NonAction` in Edit POST Action too?

Comment: @Willy yes, it's better you put it on both actions, so that POST edit action will not be invoked

Answer (score 1):

By using the Non Action method you can able to achive this like

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
     // Your Code for doing someThing
}
```

Instead of the above one please use the below code.

```
private ActionResult Edit()
{
   // Your Code for doing someThing
}
```

If you use like this means you will not able to access the Edit action method.

Comment: Is there any reason why do you use `private` instead of `[NonAction]`?

Comment: It is simple way to avoid using attributes to restrict accessing the action method. Using 'private' is better way then 'NonAction'